# Estimate shipping block not showing on cart page

Tags: magento-2.1

I am not able to see estimate shipping on cart page. In console getting these three errors 
[image]

I cannot find the problem where the issue exist.
Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: that error was due to js of my custom shipping extension.

Comment: In case anybody else strand on the article... My error was caused by somebody who did an upgrade by copying the files over the rest and not deleting any files that were deleted in the new version. It caused a whole bunch of problems.